# Trying to change calendar date format

Tags: android, calendar, simpledateformat

I'm trying to convert the calendar which i set the time milliseconds  from 1 1 1970 as below:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(1417780800);
```

Although when I'm trying to convert this calendar to a string as in this format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" it always set the date as 1970-1-17 9:49:40 when it should be 2014-12-1 12:00:00

I used this way to convert the date:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String date = format.format(c.getTime());
```

Also, using this way is getting wrong:

```
String date = "" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Any idea why? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, maybe I wasn't clear enough, I set a date on a calendar using setTimeInMillis(1417780800) (meaning the date 2014-12-1 12:00:00), but when i try to set a format from that calendar for example "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" it always shows the date in string as 1970-1-17 9:49:40

Comment: but why do you want the date to be in MiliSeconds, as you retrive it ?

Comment: I receive a milliseconds date from 1 1 1970 and I want to set the date more user friendly as for example YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: OK, let me understand this correct. the `c.setTimeInMillis(x)`, what is now in the `c`? Because `x` (the miliseconds) are the amount of milliseconds to get to the year 2014 for example, from 1970. So 44 years converted into miliseconds?

Comment: I think the website I was using was not converting the milliseconds correctly from 1 1 1970 because the website was saying milliseconds and that number was in seconds. My fault here guys.

Thanks for all the help, and sorry the inconvenience!!

Comment: Exactly, that's what I got! I converted that number to get years, and I got 44 years, but if I counted that number as **SECONDS** and not **MILLISECONDS**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like...

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(1417780800);
```

It will return Date in String format.

> Jan 17, 1970